# Paperclip with S3 - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am trying to use Paperclip gem with Amazon S3 in my Rails 3.2 application. However, the problem appears when I am adding :storage => :s3 and S3 information and generating form.

**Error:**

```
undefined method `photo' for #<PlacePhoto:0x007fdbbd1e75a8>
```

Extracted source (around line #78):

```
75:   <% end %>
76: 
77:   <%= f.simple_fields_for :place_photos do |photo| %>
78:     <%= photo.input :photo %>
79:     <%= photo.input :description,
80:       :label => "Photo label",
81:       :input_html => { :class => 'span4', :rows => 2 } %>
```

**Model:**

```
class PlacePhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo, 
    :styles => { :medium => "300x300#", :thumb => "100x100#" },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"
  attr_accessible :description, :photo

  belongs_to :place

  validates_attachment :photo,
    :presence => true,
    :content_type => { :content_type => /image/ },
    :size => { :in => 0..2.megabytes }
end
```

**Migration**

```
class CreatePlacePhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :place_photos do |t|
      t.text :description
      t.integer :place_id
      t.has_attached_file :photo

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I used the folowing article to implement S3: http://doganberktas.com/2010/09/14/amazon-s3-and-paperclip-rails-3/ . I did bundle install, rake db:migrate and restarted the server.

What is interesting, the error does not appear and the form is being generated when the model lack S3 info:

**Model (other version):**

```
class PlacePhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo, 
    :styles => { :medium => "300x300#", :thumb => "100x100#" }
  attr_accessible :description, :photo

  belongs_to :place

  validates_attachment :photo,
    :presence => true,
    :content_type => { :content_type => /image/ },
    :size => { :in => 0..2.megabytes }
end
```

Comment: I do not know Paperclip S3 support very well, but I think you should fill :bucket option to target paperclip which bucket needed to be used to pic upload.

Comment: Buckets are defined in config/s3.yml

Comment: you ran migrations too? and full error please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by changing:

```
:s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
```

To

```
:s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
```